# Package candidate/alternative for the python-pgsql package in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, apt, python, postgresql

What is the package candidate or alternative for the python-pgsql (module) package in Ubuntu 11.10 ?

An error indicator that could help:

`Error: You need to have the python-pgsql module installed to use this script.  'apt-get install python-pgsql' on debian.`

**UPDATE:**

The [davical-cmdlnutl](https://sourceforge.net/projects/davical-cmdlnut/files/1.2.0/) version 1.2.0 works.

Comment: The relevant [change](http://davical-cmdlnut.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/davical-cmdlnut/trunk/davical-cmdlnutl?r1=24&r2=25) for 1.2.0 dropped `python-pgsql` and replaced it with `python-pygresql`, corresponding to a module `pgdb` in the python imports list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian developers [suggest](http://bugs.debian.org/577664) either [python-psycopg2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/python-psycopg2) or [python-pygresql](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/python-pygresql). They have [removed](http://bugs.debian.org/620494) the package from their distribution, [as has Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/i386/python-pgsql). There might be some code changes required to use the new packages. You might ask the author of the script you intend to use to adjust his code to those packages.

**Adapting davical-cmdlnut to psycopg2**

There should be a pretty straight-forward translation between pyPgSQL and psycopg2. The different handling of quoting is perhaps the most difficult to do among these.

- pyPgSQL.PgSQL.connect → [psycopg2.connect](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect)
- pyPgSQL.libpq.DatabaseError → [psycopg2.DatabaseError](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.DatabaseError)
- pyPgSQL.libpq.PgQuoteString(s) → [psycopg2.extensions.adapt](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.adapt)(s).[getquoted](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html?highlight=quot#psycopg2.extensions.QuotedString.getquoted)()

Also note that psycopg2 developers [advise](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#sql-injection) *strongy* against the use of + to compose querys, which davical-cmdlnut does all over the place. That's the reason they have to do so much manual quoting, whereas psycopg2 would do all that automatically if parameters were passed [their way](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Comment: `python-pygresql` should work, its in the repos.

Comment: @LordofTime: Both are in the repos, as the links indicate. The documents the Debian guys referred to indicate Psycopg as more powerful and more compliant with Python DB-API, so as long as its GNU license is no problem, it might be the better suggestion.

Comment: @LordofTime: Both of these packages are not working for me!

Comment: “Not working” as in “the script does not work out of the box with those”? As I said, you'll probably have to adjust it, or get it adjusted. The packages provide replacement functionality, but no drop-in compatible API. If the script uses [Python DB API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), then those modifications should be minimal, only at connection initiation. If it uses custom code, more work will be required.

Comment: I like your answer :)